# How can I specify a module as a Type Hint in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, type-hinting

I am using Python and [Type Hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) with the libraries `typing` and `types`, and cannot get through the following code with out errors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nb_mypy
%load_ext nb_mypy
%reload_ext nb_mypy
%nb_mypy On
%nb_mypy DebugOff
from typing import Tuple, Union, Dict, List, Any
from types import ModuleType  # FrameType, TracebackType

i: List[str]
j: List[ModuleType] # I couldn't find the Type Hint for modules...

for i, j in zip(
    ['numpy', 'pandas'],
    [np, pd]):
    print(f"{i} used in this code is version {j.__version__}")
```

At the moment I get errors:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "list[str]")  [assignment]
error: "list[Module]" has no attribute "__version__"  [attr-defined]
```

I tried it with `Any` too, and got this instead, which is no better:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "list[str]")  [assignment]
error: "list[Any]" has no attribute "__version__"  [attr-defined]
```

Comment: Why are you annotating `i` and `j` as lists when you're not going to assign lists to them?

Comment: Aside from mixing up lists and elements, why not make a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for _"things with a `__version__`"_?

Comment: Typing `i` and `j` properly as `str` and `ModuleType`, not lists of those clears up all errors.

Comment: Hi @user2357112, I thought I was assign lists to them within the for loop: `for i, j in zip(['numpy', 'pandas'], [np, pd])`; am I not?

Comment: @johnukfr no, you are assigning strings to `i` and modules to `j` in a loop.

Comment: @johnukfr: You're not (and lists don't have a `__version__` attribute, so how were you expecting `j.__version__` to work if you thought you were assigning a list to `j`?)

Comment: And it's important to note that not all modules have `__version__` attribute.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I'm itterating through them (str's and modules) in a list, not itterating though a list of them!
Thank you @matszwecja.

Comment: This also clears up @user2357112's comment, I wasn't actually assign lists to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the comments, but new answers did not get it right so I thought of posting it myself instead. Turns out I was itterating through the objects in question (str's and modules) in a list, not itterating though a list of them! I had to make that explicit in the code:

```
i: str
j: ModuleType

for i, j in zip(
    ['numpy', 'pandas'],
    [np, pd]):
    print(f"{i} used in this code is version {j.__version__}")
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is with the variable names for the zip iteration. You have type-hinted variables i and j, but you use the same names for loop iteration variables, resulting in a type mismatch. Simply rename one of them, and I believe the problem will be solved.