# How can I specify a tzinfo object as a Type Hint in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, type-hinting

Would you know what is the correct type to use when specifying `datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo`?

I tried specifying the type of this `datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo` Python (3.10.5) object using Type Hints in several ways (thus the libraries imported in the code below), but this far nothing works and I get `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "tzinfo | None", variable has type "timezone")  [assignment]`. I already looked at [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788062/how-can-i-specify-a-module-as-a-type-hint-in-python/76788811#76788811) in vain...

```
import nb_mypy
%load_ext nb_mypy
%reload_ext nb_mypy
%nb_mypy On
%nb_mypy DebugOff

import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from typing import Generator, Any
from types import ModuleType
from pytz.tzinfo import DstTzInfo, StaticTzInfo

time_zn_in_graph: timezone = datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo
```

I settled on `timezone`  above because that's the type I get:

`print(type(datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo))`

`<class 'datetime.timezone'>`

but I still get the error...

[image]

Comment: You can answer such questions by consulting [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/datetime.pyi#L254). `datetime.datetime().tzinfo` property is typed to return `datetime.tzinfo` type (which is an ABC defined above in the same file). This is done to allow `pytz` timezones without including them into standard library typeshed.